How to toggle command-line window through keybindings?
My attempt:
def ToggleCmdWindow()
  if empty(getcmdwintype())
    norm! q:
  else
    quit
  endif
enddef

nnoremap <c-c> <ScriptCmd>ToggleCmdWindow()<cr>

But it immediately open and close the command-line window.

:normal q: by itself, executed manually from within vim, seems to cause the immediate open-and-close behaviour. I'm not entirely sure why, although I think it might have something to do with the <CR> used to run the command being transmitted to the command-line window (which closes it).
However, from this answer, you can use feedkeys("q:", "n") to open the command-line window without this open-and-close happening. Replacing norm! q: with this fixes your issue.
